# Array isn't updating from loop

Tags: arrays, c, loops

New to programming so I'm sure this is a mess, but it seems like my code isn't updating the values in my array, or at least it isn't printing the appropriate values, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong
I'm not sure if it's my loop that needs updating or if it's main or my functions, the lecture my teacher provided wasn't much help to me so I'm hoping someone here can provide some insight

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define SENTINEL -1
void updateLevel (int playerPoints, int b[]);

int main(void)
{
    int updateLevel;
    int displayLevels;
    int levelArray[6];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        levelArray[i] = 0;
    }
    int playerPoints;
    printf ("Player points (-1 to quit): ", SENTINEL);
    scanf ("%d", &playerPoints);
    
    while (playerPoints != SENTINEL)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("Player points (-1 to quit): ", SENTINEL);
        scanf ("%d", &playerPoints);
        void updateLevel(playerPoints, levelArray);
        
    }
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("T O T A L S\n");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Level 1\t");
    printf ("%d\n", &levelArray[1]);
    printf ("Level 2\t");
    printf ("%d\n", &levelArray[2]);
    printf ("Level 3\t");
    printf ("%d\n", &levelArray[3]);
    printf ("Level 4\t");
    printf ("%d\n", &levelArray[4]);
    printf ("Level 5\t");
    printf ("%d\n", &levelArray[5]);
    printf ("Level 6\t");
    printf ("%d\n", &levelArray[6]);
}

void updateLevel(int playerPoints, int b[])
{
    int updateLevel;
    if ((playerPoints > -1) && (playerPoints < 10))
    {
        b[1]++;
    }   
    if ((playerPoints > 9) && (playerPoints < 20))
    {
        b[2]++;
    }
    if ((playerPoints > 19) && (playerPoints < 30))
    {
        b[3]++;
    }
    if ((playerPoints > 29) && (playerPoints < 40))
    {
        b[4]++;
    }
    if ((playerPoints > 39) && (playerPoints < 50))
    {
        b[5]++;
    }
    if (playerPoints > 49)
    {
        b[6]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to have a function named `updateLevel` and a local variable with the same name.

Comment: Ever heard of `else`? or `for`? That `SENTINEL` mess made sense on 8-bit embedded systems in 1989, but these days... sigh.

Comment: You have several issues. Please compile with warnings on. If using GCC, pass the `-Wall` flag. This will prove most instructive.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

`void updateLevel(int playerPoints, int* b[]);`

then later put
`void updateLevel(int playerPoints, int* b[]) {`

The * operator makes something a pointer, so instead of allocating more ram for b it just sets it to point to levelArray in the ram.

Comment: I appreciate the help as well as understanding that I'm very new to this!
Just for clarification, you're saying to update the function updateLevel to include a return for b, would I set this array to 6 then?
How would I call this function then? At the end of my loop?
Again, sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm not sure this teacher is explaining things very well for me

Comment: It seems now like I'm getting 2 errors, one in main and one in the updateLevel function.
The main error still says that updateLevel isn't a function or function pointer, and the function error refers to the return in the function "return (b[6]);" and says it makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Yeah I updated it there as well. Changing the return at the end of the function cleared the function error but main still isn't calling it for some reason

Comment: Line 28:  levelArray = updateLevel(playerPoints, b);
This is the only error

Comment: Same error, should I change what the function is acting on?

Comment: This isn't working either, no matter what I seem to try, I just can't get this function to be called by main

Comment: Yeah I keep getting "called object 'updateLevel' is not a function or a function pointer

Comment: Seems that I'm back where I was originally, program compiles now but each element of the array isn't updating how it should.
When it prints at the end each element in the array is printing 6487556 or something close to that

Comment: dude idk whats up, try & instead of *

Comment: I appreciate the help homie, you've been going back and forth with me for awhile now. I think I'm gonna take a break for a bit tonight, I still have time to figure this one out

Comment: alr if the & doesnt work something else is wrong